# How to restrict user from entering value in webview, Android?

Tags: android, webview

How to restrict user from entering value in the webView, in android.

In my android application i have a webView which shows some textareas, checkboxes, radiobuttons etc... This app has a read only mode in which the user can see only the contents he entered earlier in the webView.

But how to restrict user from re-entering values??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your `WebView` to not be clickable in your layout xml:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:longClickable="false"
```

You can also try to remove the focus from it:

```
myWebView.setEnabled(false);
```

and/or

```
myWebView.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

Comment: that didn't do the job!! my webview has textareas, checkboxes, radiobuttons etc... the user still can edit them!

Comment: Ok, then you can setup a javascript interface on your webview and call it to disable your elements with some javascript code inside your html file. You might also consider having another html file that only displays the info you want instead of having all these checkboxes and textareas.

Comment: edit: it works on lower API versions, but not on kitkat! Think its better to disable the UI elements by JS Script!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I can't approve edits though. Hope someone with permissions will see to it.